# How to convert a sparse dict to scipy.sparse matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy

I have a very large dictionary of the following format `{str: [0, 0, 1, 2.5, 0, 0, 0, ...], str: [0, 0, 0, 1.1, 0, 0, ...], ...}`. The number of elements for each str key can be very big so I need an effective way to store and make calculations over this data. 
For example right now my dict of str keys has 100 keys. Each key has one value which is a list of 7000 float elements. The length of str keys and values is constant. So, let's say str key is of length 5 and its value (which is a list) is 7000.

After some reading I found that **scipy.sparse** module has a nice collection of various matrices to store sparse data but scipy documentation is so *sparse* that I can barely understand what's going on.

Can you provide an example of how to convert the dictionary above to correct matrix type?

Comment: No expert, but I think you need to clarify what shape your matrix will have (regular NxM or key vector lenths can vary), if keys in dict has an meaningful order and for efficiency what type of calculations you expect to perform.

Comment: added information about matrix shape

Comment: I cannot really see how is your data structure a matrix. What kind of operations do you do with it that would need a matrix representation (since there are different sparse matrix formats which are good for different things, this question is important)? Perhaps it will be enough to just transform the lists to ``numpy`` arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With standard `dict` methods you can get a list of the keys, and another list of the values.  Pass the 2nd to `numpy.array` and you should get a 100 x 7000 array.  The keys list could also be made into array, but it might not be any more useful than the list.  The values array could be turned into a sparse matrix.  But its size isn't exceptional, and arrays have more methods.

Tomorrow I can add sample code if needed.

Comment: I was erroneously thinking that dict can be converted into matrix without extracting values into list somehow. I don't think that manipulating a few more huge lists in memory is efficient.

Comment: The `dict.values()` list contains pointers to the same lists as in the dictionary (compare `id()`s).  There's no data copying.  But copying is done when creating an array, so it can all be accessed efficiently with C code.